# Semantic Mapping

Tags: gazebo, rviz, knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1-) What is the needs for semantic mapping ?!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45757/semantic-mapping/) by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 238 on 2012-10-12

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-12**:
Can you please create single questions for each of your questions?

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2012-10-13**:
OK, I will :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Semantic maps describe the poses, types and properties of objects in the robot's environment. They are useful whenever a robot needs to interact with these objects.

As an introduction, you may want to have a look at the paper [Autonomous Semantic Mapping for Robots Performing Everyday Manipulation Tasks in Kitchen Environments](http://ias.cs.tum.edu/_media/spezial/bib/mapping11iros.pdf) that describes both how these maps can be acquired and how they are internally represented. You can also create the internal representation manually, using the [semantic map editor or a ROS service](http://ias.in.tum.de/kb/wiki/index.php/Mod_semantic_map).

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2012-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2012-10-14**:
Is it help robot to infer messing component for setting a table as example ?!

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2012-10-14**:
Does it need Knowledge enable cognitive perception for manipulation
K-CoPMAN ?!!